# how do I resolve this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String option = args[0];
        String filename = args[1];

        if ( !(option.equals("-f")) && !(option.equals("-d")) ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            printUsage();
        }

        GreenhouseControls gc = new GreenhouseControls();
        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("-f")) {
            gc.addEvent(gc.new Restart(0,filename));
            gc.run();
        }else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("-d")){
            Restore restore = new Restore(filename);
        }
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number of parameters");
        printUsage();
    }
}
```

There is an error because of the public void main ( String[] args) and I dont know why. It says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: You're using Eclipse right? Then open the Markers view or the Problems view, and don't even think about running your code while compilation errors are still listed in these views. Read the compilation error messages to know what and where the problem is. And please, for your own good, indent your code.

Comment: Are you importing the `GreenhouseControls ` class? I'm guessing it cannot find it at compilation time

Comment: i think you dont have import of some the class .Most probably  GreenhouseControls or Restart .Make sure you have imported all the used class and there is no compile time error

Comment: printUsage is static method and plz paste complete class

Comment: on which line you are getting error?

Comment: Is Restart your inner class?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
gc.addEvent(gc.new Restart(0,filename));
```

to

```
gc.addEvent(new Restart(0,filename));
```